# return the index of 1 in an array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say we have a numpy array like this `[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]`, we want to change that array into one where the ith entry is the index of 1 in the ith subarray of the original array. In the above case, we want to get `[0,1,2]` as return value.

Is there a library method in numpy to do that?

Answer (score 2):

For a binary (only 1 and zeros) array, you could use [numpy.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
print(arr.argmax(axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
[0 1 2]
```

If there are other values, and you want to find the 1s, you could use:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 5], [6, 7, 1]])
print((arr == 1).argmax(axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
[0 1 2]
```

Notice that this also works for the binary case.